# is it ok to change the database table schemas created from rails using mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I created some tables using rails. Now I want to modify the structure of a few of them. I know it can be done using rails migration. But i was wondering if it would cause any anomaly in the rails app if I modify the schemas using mysql rdbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing such changes through a migration has the advantage of not losing the changes if you decide to recreate/remigrate the database.

Also it serves as documentation. Imagine if your coworker altered some tables sneakily (and then you both forgot about it).

Technically, updating schemas directly in the database should  work, but don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

To add to `Sergio`'s point, you're missing a simple fact - [Rails' migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) create the famous `db/schema.rb` file - from which your migrations pull all their data.

The importance of `schema.rb` is overlooked - it is one of the most crucial aspects of your application.

**db/schema.rb**

[image]

The schema gives all your migrations a *version* of your DB to change / add to. Each time you perform a migration, Rails changes the schema file to ensure it has a "blueprint" of your db stored on file.

The schema is then able to rebuild the database using such methods as `rake db:schema:load` (ONLY RECOMMENDED FOR NEW INSTALLS -- DELETES PREVIOUS DATA)

---

So whilst there's no problem setting up the db using the db's own native tools, I recommend against it. You need to keep your migrations up to speed so that Rails can build the appropriate tables from its schema.